# How can I make sure that the borders of the text content do not go under the photo?

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKHy3.png)
Html

```
 <p><img src="index-foto1.jpg" align="left" width=65% style="border-radius: 10px;" margin-right: 2px>
      <div class="tant"><h3>Более подробно о Вышнем Волочке можно узнать по данным ссылкам:</h3></div></p>
```

CSS

```
.tant{
border:solid;
background-color: d18924;
}
```

How to make sure that the borders do not go beyond the photo?

The screenshot shows everything. I tried to put margin, I thought it would help. Also tried to restrict div to elements.

Comment: Try flex: `p{display: flex; gap: 1em}`

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you write `align: left`, you actually mean `float: left` ? If that's the case, try this :

```css
img {
  border-radius: 10px; 
  float: left; 
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.tant {
  background-color: pink; 
  border: 1px solid; 
  display: flow-root;
}
```

```html
<p><img src="//unsplash.it/800/800" width=65% >
  <div class="tant">
  <h3>Более подробно о Вышнем Волочке можно узнать по данным ссылкам:</h3>
  </div>
</p>
```